# C++ - Regarding the scope of dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I have a quick question regarding the scope of dynamic arrays, which I assume is causing a bug in a program I'm writing. This snippet checks a function parameter and branches to either the first or the second, depending on what the user passes.

When I run the program, however, I get a scope related error:

```
error: ‘Array’ was not declared in this scope
```

Unless my knowledge of C++ fails me, I know that variables created within a conditional fall out of scope when when the branch is finished. However, I dynamically allocated these arrays, so I cannot understand why I can't manipulate the arrays later in the program, since the pointer should remain.

```
        //Prepare to store integers
        if (flag == 1) {
                int *Array;
                Array = new int[input.length()]; 
            } 
        //Prepare to store chars
        else if (flag == 2) {
                char *Array;
                Array = new char[input.length()];
            }
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I'm probably going to end up changing the entire structure of this method due to the comments here. Thanks for all of help and the wide variety of solutions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `Array` before `if`. And you can't declare array of different types as one variable, so I think you should use to pointers.

```
int *char_array = nullptr;
int *int_array  = nullptr;

//Prepare to store integers
if (flag == 1) {
    int_array = new int[input.length()]; 
} 
//Prepare to store chars
else if (flag == 2) {
    char_array = new char[input.length()];
}

if (char_array)
{
    //do something with char_array
}
else if (int_array)
{
    //do something with int_array
}
```

Also as j_random_hacker points, you might want to change you program design to avoid lot's of `if`

Comment: That won't work for the second path, which notice uses an array of characters instead.

Answer (score 3):

While you are right that since you dynamically allocated them on the heap, the memory won't be released to the system until you explicitly delete it (or the program ends), the *pointer* to the memory falls out of scope when the block it was declared in exits.  Therefore, your pointer(s) need to exist at a wider scope if they will be used after the block.

Comment: You're right, but your answer has the same problem as the one you pointed out on Andrew's answer, which you apparently downvoted...?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I was trying to answer his/her question more generally since he didn't seem to understand the distinction b/w the pointer and the memory. (Just added the "(s)" to make that more obvious.) Also I figured Andrew would give the code. (Yes, I upvoted it ater he fixed it.)

Answer (score 3):

The memory remains *allocated* (i.e. taking up valuable space), there's just no way to access it after the closing `}`, because at that point the program loses the ability to address it.  To avoid this, you need to assign the pointer returned by `new[]` to a pointer variable declared in an outer scope.

As a separate issue, it looks as though you're trying to allocate memory of one of 2 different types.  If you want to do this portably, you're obliged to either use a `void *` to hold the pointer, or (less commonly done) a `union` type containing a pointer of each type.  Either way, you will need to maintain state information that lets the program know which kind of allocation has been made.  **Usually, wanting to do this is an indication of poor design**, because every single access will require switching on this state information.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intend correctly what you are trying to do is: depending on some logic allocate memory to store *n* elements of either `int` or `char` and then later in your function **access** that array as either `int` or `char` without the need for a single `if` statement.

If the above understanding is correct than the simple answer is: "C++ is a strong-typed language and what you want is not possible".

However... C++ is also an extremely powerful and flexible language, so here's what can be done:

**Casting**. Something like the following:

```
void * Array;
if(flag1) Array = new int[len]
else Array = new char[len];
// ... later in the function
if(flag) // access as int array
  int i = ((int*)Array)[0];
```

Yes, this is ugly and you'll have to have those `if`s sprinkled around the function. So here's an alternative: **template**

```
template<class T> T foo(size_t _len)
{
  T* Array = new T[_len];
  T element = Array[0];
  return element;
}
```

Yet another, even more obscure way of doing things, could be the use of `union`s:

```
union int_or_char {int i; char c;};
int_or_char *Array = new int_or_char[len];
if(flag) // access as int
  int element = Array[0].i;
```

But one way or the other (or the third) there's no way around the fact that the **compiler** has to know how to deal with the data you are trying to work with.

Comment: You will still have to create the template array specifying it's type. It does not eliminate if

Comment: @Andrew: True, but you can potentially write *all* the code that needs to manipulate the array as function templates (even if the behaviour is sometimes different between types, this can be handled by writing function templates and specialising them).  Then one top-level `if (flag == 1) use<int>(); else use<char>();` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Turix's answer is right. You need to keep in mind that two things are being allocated here, The memory for the array and the memory when the location of the array is stored.

So even though the memory from the array is allocated from the heap and will be available to the code where ever required, the memory where the location of the array is stored (the Array variable) is allocated in the stack and will be lost as soon as it goes out of scope. Which in this case is when the if block end. You can't even use it in the else part of the same if.

Another different code suggestion from Andrew I would give is :

```
void *Array = nullptr;

if (flag == 1) {
    Array = new int[input.length()];
} else if (flag == 2) {
    Array = new char[input.length()];
}
```

Then you can directly use if as you intended.

<strike>This part I am not sure : In case you want to know if its an int or char you can use the [**typeid**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid) literal.</strike> Doesn't work, at least I can't get it to work.

Alternatively you can use your flag variable to guess what type it is.

Comment: How do you propose to use typeid here?

Comment: `typeid` only works for either (a) a statically knowable type (e.g. `typeid (int)`) or (b) which of several derived classes a pointer or reference to a base class actually points to, and even then it requires that the base class be polymorphic (have >= 1 virtual function).  It can't possibly know what lives at the place where a `void *` is pointing.  Otherwise good.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't sure how typeid worked, but wiki says it determines type at runtime.. so theoretically it may know what kind object is located at a particular memory location. But it doesn't seem to work. I will cut it out.

Comment: How could `typeid` know if a byte contains a `char`, a `signed char` or an `unsigned char`?  No-one sticks a post-it note on that memory location ;)  (Those are 3 distinct types in C++ BTW.)